# Getting ul to appear based on page height with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrolltop, display

Ok, so I've been searching stackoverflow and google. I have found answers to this question but I have not been able to get one to work for me for some odd reason. I've also tried to write my own code in jquery to get this to work. I have checked my code doing the addendum to my style to my `<ul>` and it is working based off click function but will not work based off page height. Basically I want a selection bar to appear after scrolling down the page a little and disappear as I go back up.

HTML

```
<ul class="bttn2" id="hide" style="">   
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide1" class="bttn2" href="#aboutme">ABOUT ME</li>
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide2" class="bttn2" href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</li>
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide3" class="bttn2" href="#hobbies">HOBBIES</li>
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide4" class="bttn2" href="#school">SCHOOL</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
var element = $(".banner").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
if (y >= element){
    $('.bttn2').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

basic function:

https://jsfiddle.net/rnpp76rv

showing display none function works:

https://jsfiddle.net/rnpp76rv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

step 1. Get Location of Top of the page:

```
var topLocation = $('html').offset().top;
```

step 2. Get current location of scroll:

```
var currLocation=$(window).scrollTop();
```

step 3. compare both location and show/hide

```
if (topLocation != currLocation){
        $('#id1').show();
    }
else{
        $('#id1').hide();
    }
```

[Check fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dpanshu/nenf60p1/)